# Upon launch, I get a graphical glitch and no menu

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Minecraft Windows 10 Edition does this upon load. No menu, and <kbd>Esc</kbd> does nothing.

The white and black parts flicker randomly.

Windows 10 is fully updated, and Graphics Drivers were also updated today.

I've seen suggestions to uninstall and re-install the app, but the Microsoft Store says that it will delete all settings and stuff. Will it delete all of the saved worlds?

[image: Glitched UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from link below, this worked for me:

> "FumalliLuigi added a comment - 39 minutes ago
> Here is a solution that I found that worked for me:
>
> - Open AMD radeon settings
> - Go to Gaming tab and press Games icon; you will see Minecraft under your games
> - Press on Minecraft
> - Go to Graphics: Change profile to Standard
> - Enable: Radeon Anti Lag and  dont change  anything else
> - Launch game from there
>
> " - [Bug Tracker](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-109870)

Comment: I don't know why that worked, but it did.  Thank you.  Then, I tested it with AA and AF on, and still works.  It is an R290, old but good.

Answer (score 1):

1.16.200 has been giving me graphical bugs recently (although mine are not nearly as obstructive as this), so I’m guessing soon a 1.16.201 will roll out fixing it.

If you choose to uninstall the game, make a copy of your `com.mojang` folder in the game folders and then uninstall the game, reinstall it, and put the folder you copied back into the game. That should save all your worlds, addons, etc.